Relationship between relative PA degree and Turing reducibility.
According to Reverse Mathematics, Definition 2.8.24 by Dzhafarov–Mummert, we say that a function $f \in 2^\omega$ has PA degree relative to $g \in 2^\omega$ if the collection of $f$-computable function is a basis for $\Pi_1^{0, g}$-classes (written $f\gg g$). My question is the following: f $f \gg g$, then can we prove $f \geq_\mathrm{T} g$?

I've fixed a typo: "$\Pi^1_0$" vs. "$\Pi^0_1$."

For every $g\in 2^\omega$, the set $\{g\}$ is a $\Pi^{0,g}_1$-class (explicitly, consider the tree $\{\sigma\in 2^{<\omega}: \sigma\prec g\}$). So if $f\gg g$ then $g\le_Tf$ since $g$ is the only element of $\{g\}$.

Thank you a lot!
